# goland HTML Code Style Setting not working

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

I am using GoLand and write HTML file.
I set Tab size, Indent and Continuation indent to 2 like attached Image.
But, html files have 4 indents instead of 2.

I set these setting at Default and Project. But not working.

If anyone know about this problem.
Please tell me about it.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you bump into [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-8328). As a workaround, you can either adjust *Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Other File Types* or disable the Go template plugin if you don't use it.